# NightmareJS Nested Commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I can't figure out how to do nested commands for Nightmare. Consider the following code:

```
let userLinks = await nightmare.evaluate(function(users, nightmare) {
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var matchResult = users[i].match(/.com\/(.*?)\?fref/);
        if (matchResult) {
            var newLink = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(newLink);
            newLink.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.example.com/'+matchResult[1]);
            nightmare.click('a[href="https://www.example.com/'+matchResult[1]+'"]'); // this won't work
        }
    }
    return null;
}, users);
```

The `nightmare.click()` won't work. I get `nightmare.click is not a function`. How can this be done?

Comment: try and rename the function parameter nightmare so it doesn't clash with the nightmare instance used in nightmare.evaluate

Comment: I just tried it but I got `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. I think it's because everything within `evaluate` is executing in the document context. Not sure what to try.